# A question in basic topology (homeomorphisms, open)

Tags: general-topology

This is a question I thought by myself :

Suppose U and V are subsets of a topological space X.
Suppose U and V are homeomorphic (when considered with the subspace topology).
If U is open in X does it follow that V is open in X?

Comment: Please read carefully the post [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?r=SearchResults&s=1|132.5606).  Your question lacks any form of context.  Why is this question important to you?  What led you to think about this question?  What have you studied, or are you currently studying.  The linked post will provide you with more suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a counterexample take $X=[0,1)$, $U=[0,1/2)$, and $V=[1/2,1)$.

On the other hand, if $X = \mathbb R^n$ then this is true by application of the [invariance of domain theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain) (which is *hard* to prove). And once you know that, it's not too much harder to prove it for the more general case where $X$ is an $n$-dimensional manifold.

So, for example, although not true when $X=[0,1)$, it *is* true when $X=S^1$.

Comment: Thank you very much! What are the steps to prove that it holds for manifolds?

Comment: Here's a rough outline. If $X$ is a manifold, $U \subset X$ is open, and $V \subset X$, and $h : V \to U$ is homeomorphism, you pick $y \in V$ and $x=h(y) \in U$, and then you use manifold coordinate charts around $y$ and $x$ to reduce the problem to the $\mathbb R^n$ version. This gets you an open ball around $y$, in $V$ and in the coordinate chart.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Misread the question! Ok, we repair it: consider $X = \{0,1\}$ with the topology given by $\{\emptyset, \{0\}, X\}$. Then, $U = \{0\}$ and $V = \{1\}$ are homeomorphic as subspaces but $V$ is not open.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I can not see how it solves the question. What are U,V and X in terms of your answer?

Comment: I have edited the answer, it should address your question now!

Comment: Thank you! Very nice example